# adding some words as blocks to JTextarea

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jtextarea

We want to add some words from `JComboBox` to a `JTextArea`, but we want these words to be as blocks.

I mean that when the user tries to delete a letter from this block the whole block will be deleted.

Example:

Let the block word be "Title", then when we have this block in a `JTextArea`, we deal with it as one letter.

How can we do that?

Comment: Probably not in a JTextArea, try a JTextPane or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps attach customEditorKit to [jetTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#setEditorKit(javax.swing.text.EditorKit)) like this:
 1. Extend `EditorKit` and override `ViewFactory` to return an instance of CustomViewFactory 
2. Override method `create` in `CustomViewFactory` that implements `ViewFactory` and return 
BoxView, ComponentView, IconView(if you want to add some icon + text), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `JTextArea`'s document and add a `DocumentFilter`. Check there if offset of event is inside the block text and skip the events (either remove or insert)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can use `JTextPane` to add a `Component` to an area of text.  Then it's always treated as a whole word.  Here's an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextComponent extends Box{
    public TextComponent(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        final JTextPane textArea = new JTextPane();
        textArea.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(textArea);

        JButton addText = new JButton("Add Text");
        addText.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        addText.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel text = new JLabel("Original Text");
                text.setAlignmentY(0.8f);
                text.setOpaque(true);
                text.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                textArea.insertComponent(text);
            }});
        add(addText);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new TextComponent());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```